Deleted Answers Due to Other Websites
I don’t use this account much but I recently received an email from mods for deleted answers which I am told includes information from other websites.
These answers go back 10-11 years.
I don’t know what websites contain this information. It is possible other websites dumped the Stack Overflow data dump a long time ago and now my answers are implicated.
I don’t really have an interest in figuring out which of my answers from 10-11 years ago are flagged or where the purported websites came from.
I think this is a mistake that I should have had a chance to rectify before the answers were deleted. I should have also been given a chance to respond.

You can always flag you own content and raise a custom mod flag.

"I am told includes information from other websites.". You mean the answers were allegedly plagarised? No accusation, merely a request for clarity.

If you've received a moderator message, then you have a chance to respond to the message. That's inherent in the on-site interface. You should have a notification in your SE/SO system inbox, which will have a link to the message. The textbox in which you can enter and post a single response is just below the message. Note: You're allowed a single response following any message from moderators. This includes being able to post an additional response, if there's another message from moderators after any response you post. In other words, you always have the ability to have the last word.

I was not given a chance to respond before it was deleted about 6 hours ago. I didn’t know until I got the email.

@Paulie_D Yes allegedly. I went thru all the deleted answers and found the one in question that was deleted. I don’t even remember writing the answer over 10 years ago. But I did find my answer’s details and concepts on websites from 2022.

Yes, of course, moderators took action without asking you "is it OK if we enforce the site rules?" You are, however, of course, welcome to respond to the message and explain how we got it wrong, which we sometimes do. If you convince the moderator who performed the action (not me), or any other moderator who monitors the conversation, then the post(s) can be undeleted.

@Makyen  If it is going to be deleted then an explanation of what part is allegedly plagiarized should be provided. There is zero justification

@Paulie_D I am not admitting it is plagiarism. The investigation should have been provided. It’s no different than if you had been approached at school. There is no information to cross reference the allegation

I must admit, it feels like you aren't here to do much other than rant. Your posts were deleted, you were reached out to as to why but you don't want to reply (it seems), and don't care which posts were deleted or why. So what do you want?

@ThomA I want to know what part is plagiarized and provided to me (that’s why it’s tagged as support). A blanket delete does no one any good. Where is the result of the purported investigation?

Then reply through the mod message and discuss the deletion.

Frankly, you're opening up a can of worms here. Do you really want the details made public. The mods won't want to embarass you but that's likely to be the end result.

@Paulie_D: It can be provided via mod message. I didn’t ask for it to be made public anywhere in my original post. You are piling on here.

"A blanket delete does no one any good." It does you no good, which is part of the idea; plagiarm should not be rewarded. This is not a statement to say you did, but that the same process is applied to everyone, those who obviously plagiarised and those that make it harder to detect.

While more information could have been provided in the moderator message, it's generally assumed by moderators that you know what you did. Why should moderators have to preemptively do a lot more work on every single such message when it's trivial for the user to write back something like "I don't believe I plagiarized anything. Could you please provide more details and evidence that lead you to the conclusion that it/they was/were plagiarized?"

@Paulie_D "Even the OP admits it was plagarism." - I think what OP is arguing is that someone else plagiarised their answer and posted it on another site, then a moderator found it, mistook it for the original, and accused them of plagiarising the answer that they actually wrote originally. Whether they're telling the truth, I obviously can't say, but that's what they appear to be claiming. I certainly don't see them admitting to plagiarism anywhere.

@Makyen: I understand the perspective. It was 10 years ago. It would be like you graduated college and someone comes back to you about a paper. I have no idea.

@F1Krazy: Thank you for understanding what I am getting at

10 years doesn't matter, @Engineer2021 . I actually flagged a post that was 10 years old as plagiarism that had over 400 votes earlier this year, as I found a post that plagiarised the same content, and I found the post in my search for the original content. Time passed doesn't matter; congrats you "got away with it" for 10 years, and now youve been caught.

@ThomA: That’s a little rude- I don’t agree I got away with anything. Again, no details provided. I have since flagged the message for mods like you suggested. I didn’t plagiarize.

I think this is a mistake that I should have had a chance to rectify before the answers were deleted. You always have a chance, answers can be undeleted. However your previous sentence ...I don’t really have an interest in figuring out... suggests that you don't really want to spend any effort in your defense, so even if the moderator made a mistake, there's no way it's going to be corrected. Effectively, you're just coming here to complain. That's understandable if you've been wronged, but it really doesn't change or help anything.

I never said you did, @Engineer2021 . I commented earlier, but I'll repeat : "This is not a statement to say you did, but that the same process is applied to everyone, those who obviously plagiarised and those that make it harder to detect."

I'm not the moderator who sent you the message, but I think that the situation is clear enough for me to respond, although I have pinged them informing them of this MSO question.
Moderator messages can be directly responded to
If you've received a moderator message, then you have a chance to respond to the message. That's inherent in the on-site interface. You should have a notification in your SE/SO system inbox, which will have a link to the message. The textbox in which you can enter and post a single response is just below the message. Note: You're allowed a single response following any message from moderators. This includes being able to post an additional response, if there's another message from moderators after any response you post. In other words, you always have the ability to have the last word.
Moderators will normally take action when they find something that isn't in compliance with site rules without contacting the user prior to doing so. You are welcome to respond to the moderator message to explain the situation and/or try to convince us that we got something wrong. We do make mistakes, from time to time. When we do, we are willing to admit to them, apologize and correct the situation.
While more information could have been provided in the moderator message, it's generally assumed by moderators that you know what you did. Why should moderators have to preemptively do a lot more work on every single such message when it's trivial for the user to write back something like "I don't believe I plagiarized anything. Could you please provide more details and evidence that lead you to the conclusion that it/they was/were plagiarized?" On the other hand, I agree that the moderator message could have stated that only one post was deleted and link to it.
A single answer was deleted, and it did contain plagiarism.
Only a single answer of yours was deleted: answer to: "Why List.contains() takes Object as an argument in Collections Java". You could determine this from your list of deleted answers to which you were linked in the moderator message.
Everything above the first horizontal line in your 2014 answer to: "Why List.contains() takes Object as an argument in Collections Java" is a direct copy and paste from answer to: "Writing contains() for a generic collection" from 2011 (never edited).
The post clearly copies and clearly doesn't follow How to reference material written by others, so it was deleted and a moderator message sent informing you both of the deletion and of Stack Overflow's policies on posting copied content.

I clearly made a mistake back then of not citing the original StackOverflow answer from 2011. I disagree it constitutes plagiarism since it’s on the site. But I will own up to the mistake

But it was plagiarism, @Engineer2021 . The sites has strict guidelines on including others content, which includes putting said content in a quote block (which you omitted), citing the origin source (which you omitted), citing the author (which you omitted), and ensuring your post isn't solely copied content (which you did have). Perhaps sof you can elaborate how you met those guidelines, it would help us underderstand why you think it isn't plagiarism.

@Engineer2021 It is plagiarism. Plagiarism is representing, either explicitly or implicitly, work that isn't yours as your own. Anything you post on Stack Exchange is represented as your own work, unless you make it clear that it's not your own work. Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange has further requirements that you must follow the referencing requirements when posting work that's not your own, and posts might be deleted and the user mod messaged for not following those requirements, but making something not plagiarism merely requires saying that the work isn't yours.

@ThomA: I started using the site almost when it first launched and over time the site policies and standards have changed. I honestly hadn’t kept up with them. If I was aware back then that was the policy then I would have been operating that way. But I think in that time the site has matured, I have matured. Knowing the policy now, I would have linked the other answer as part of my answer. I made a mistake in 2014. So any answers if I provide them moving forward will be properly cited.

Note that there are even further requirements to comply with copyright when quoting content. For content from SE, you also must comply with CC BY-SA, which requires even more than the referencing requirements (my answer on MSO detailing requirements for CC BY-SA 3.0). However, moderators don't enforce copyright. We do enforce the referencing requirements.

@Makyen: I agree to meet the requirements moving forward. In 2014, that site policy was not as clear (not speaking to CC BY-SA as I am not trained on that). It is good the site published an official policy today especially regarding AI.

@Engineer2021 Thanks, that's great. We appreciate you're paying attention to the requirements in the future. Making sure you were aware of those requirements and complying in the future is the primary goal of sending such a moderator message. Note that you could edit the post to bring it into compliance with the referencing requirements and then flag it requesting that it be undeleted. In general, that's permitted when the post has content other than just the copied content, which is certainly the case here.

@Engineer2021 - If you do not quote and cite a source, that is plagiarism. The only recourse would be to fix your mistake and properly cite and quote the source material. Do you care enough about the single contribution that was deleted? You have never been able to plagiarize another SO user or claim you were the author of material you were not the actual author of. To say the rules have changed in that regard is a red herring. Saying you plan not to plagiarize and adequately cite material from now on is an odd statement since it's a requirement whether or not you agree.

@SecurityHound: I understand it’s now a requirement to cite other answers that either you used or inspired your answer. I didn’t treat this site like academia in the past. But knowing this rule I will do it moving forward - but I don’t post much on SO these days. I think I have explained myself. It’s been a long time since I have used SO and was surprised. Completely forgot all about it. The flag as I stated never showed me what was the problem. This should be improved when a post is deleted so people know what to fix because it wasn’t my entire answer. A part of it

@SecurityHound: For the record, the answer I was referring to has been revised and restored

@Engineer2021—You need to understand that it was always a requirement. Plagiarizing content has always been against the rules. Just because your original contribution was not flagged recently does not mean it didn't plagiarize another SO user's answer. You bring up academia, but not plagiarizing somebody isn't allowed in the professional world, either.

@SecurityHound: agree to disagree. At my job, we don’t reference each other’s documents. While duplication isn’t great because it leads to less single sources of truth, we don’t cite all over the place. I have worked at many different companies for over 20 years. Including military for 20

@Engineer2021, I was thinking more along the lines that you cannot plagiarize somebody else outside your organization. Please don't try to defend plagiarism. Your comments make it sound like you are defending plagiarism, and I know that you know that plagiarism is not allowed in modern society.

@SecurityHound I don’t agree with the idea that it’s plagiarism to use another answer but I will follow the side guidelines moving forward

@SecurityHound: as far another org, we will commonly reference other material as long as it’s not copyrighted. This is normal. Never not been the case

@SecurityHound Unfortunately, we can't really go so far as to say "plagiarism is not allowed in modern society". There are, unfortunately, many modern societies where plagiarism is very common, even expected. We can say that in the vast majority of Western societies, plagiarism is not acceptable, and will often get you at least censured.

@Engineer2021 -  to steal and pass off (the ideas or words of another) as one's own : use (another's production) without crediting the source.  Copying and pasting another user's answer and claiming it as your own words (by submitting the answer) would be plagiarism based on that definition. We won't see eye to eye on this subject.  I won't be returning.

"I started using the site almost when it first launched and over time the site policies and standards have changed." The rules on referencing were, however, the same in 2013 as they are now though, so applied to your post in April 2014.

@Engineer2021 "I disagree it constitutes plagiarism since it’s on the site" - that's Stack Overflow, if you take wording literally as they appear in a dictionary you will reason yourself into a downward spiral. Stack Overflow has alternative homegrown definitions of plagiarism, duplicate, quality and spam (not an exhaustive list), you really need to know what is implied by them on this site specifically. Luckily, it's documented. And then there is the undocumented stuff, like people calling questions "bad" when they only imply "not on-topic for Stack Overflow". It's a site with a fat manual.
